# Xcode Interface Builder Style Guide - How to add colors

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

In interface builder there are MANY attributes where you pick a color by using the "Colors" dialog.  I recently noticed a new tab that kind of looks like a sun on the far right.  When I click there, I see a message: "No colors in the styleguide.  Go add some!"  So my question is...How?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tab is added by [Zeplin](https://zeplin.io/). To add colors to the styleguide, you have to design your UI in Zeplin and save the colors in its styleguide using the small button in the right panel.

[image]

The colors will then be available in XCode.

[image: XCode Interface Builder with Zeplin styleguide colors]

Comment: Unfortunately this is broken in Xcode 8. It works in other macOS apps though.

Comment: Huh? I've never seen that sun... I use Zeplin.

Comment: As @RolandT. already mentioned, this is broken in Xcode 8 since Apple killed the external plugins support in this version. See conversation on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/zeplin_io/status/821870255710420992)